# Eloquent fetch records after current time with AM/PM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table time_slots and i want to get time records after current time.
Here is my eloquent query

```
    date_default_timezone_set('asia/kolkata');
    $current_time = date('h:i A');
    $diet_list['time_slot_list'] = DB::table('time_slot as a')
    ->select('a.*')
    ->whereNotIn('a.id', $results)
    ->where('time', '>', $current_time)
    ->get()->toArray();
```

**Description:** suppose this time 06:15 PM and i want fatch record after 06:15 PM , i am getting record after  06:15 PM but also comming 10:00 AM 10:30 AM 11:00 AM 11:30 AM 12:00 PM 12:30 PM with record i do not want to record before 06:15 PM

[image]

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  suppose this time 06:15 PM and i want fatch record after 06:15 PM , i am getting record after 06:15 PM but also comming 10:00 AM 10:30 AM 11:00 AM 11:30 AM 12:00 PM 12:30 PM with record i do not want to record before 06:15 PM

Comment: what I mean, is that you should have thought at this at the beginning... just think how much easier this would be if you would have saved this like "minutes from midnight" instead of using this format

Comment: its exiting project

Comment: what's the data type of the 'time' column?

Comment: news about the answer?

Comment: data type of the 'time' column is string

Answer (score -1):

As suggested on the comments section, you should use minutes from midnight to make easier the calculation... in particular, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM time_slot 
WHERE 
 HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('...', '%I:%i %p')) * 60 + MINUTE(STR_TO_DATE('...', '%I:%i %p')) 
    >=
 """minutes"""
```

and using query builder dialectic should be:

```
date_default_timezone_set('asia/kolkata');
$current_time = date('h:i A');
$diet_list['time_slot_list'] = DB::table('time_slot as a')
    ->select('a.*')
    ->where(DB::raw("HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('...', '%I:%i %p')) * 60 + MINUTE(STR_TO_DATE('...', '%I:%i %p')) "), '>', (time() - strtotime("today")) / 60)
    ->get()->toArray();
```